# Mysterious membership-relation question in Enderton's `Elements of Set-Theory'

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question I am currently working on states (mysteriously): ``Simplify $\in^{-1}_{\omega} [\{7,8\}]$". For those who have the text, this is exercise #18 in Enderton's `Elements of Set Theory' on page 88.

I have a few ideas about what is meant but as I try to work through each idea, I end up having no clue.

$\bf{Idea \ \#1}$: $\in^{-1}_{\omega}$ is the inverse binary-relation on the natural numbers. So when the questions asks to simplify $\in^{-1}_{\omega} [\{7,8\}]$, it is asking me to find the domain of $\{7,8\}$ (because $[\{7,8\}] $ is the range of the binary relation). But this means asking for the set $S = \{x \in \omega \ | \ x \in_{\omega} \{7,8\}\}$. I had this idea because we have on page 44 of Enderton the following definition of ``the image of A under F" where $F$ is a relation: $f[A] = ran(F \restriction A) = \{v \ | \ (\exists u \in A) \ uFv\}$. But then, it seems I'm left with $\in^{-1}_{\omega} [\{7,8\}]$ = $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ since 7 is already a member of 8 so we just consider all of the members of 7.

$\bf{Idea \ \#2}$: Since this exercise is assigned after a section on linear-orderings, I have to do something involving well-ordering or induction with this question.

$\bf{Idea \ \#3}$: Something involving transitive sets, where a set $T$ is transitive iff $x \in y \in T \implies x \in T$

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I vote for Idea n°1 : I think the Ex is relative to the ordering relation $\in_{\omega}$ defind bottom page 83.

Comment: Ah thank you very much for catching that for me! I had missed this definition in the textbook... Much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, the question still does not make sense to me even after spending a few hours with the definition. I do not understand what it means to say that there is a range for the membership-relation over a set with $two$ numbers - namely, 7 and 8.

Comment: The set is defined as : $\in_{\omega} = \{ <m, n> \in \omega \times \omega | m \in n \}$. Because, by "construction", $m \in n$ iff $m < n$, we have that e.g. $0 \in 1$ and $7 \in 8$. Thus we are searching for the elements of $\omega$ that are "mapped" into $\{ 7,8 \}$ by $\in_{\omega}$; this is the meaning of  $\in_{\omega}^{-1}[{7,8}]$ ...

Comment: Thank you Mauro for helping to clarify. What I am still confused about is that we are given two numbers: 7 and 8. Since $7 \in 8$, and 7 is transitive, every element of 7 will be in 8. So I am confused since it seems redundant that they are asking for \{7,8\} rather than just simply \{8\}. 

Also, since it is $\in^{-1}_{\omega}$, aren't we considering all of the elements that are ``super-members" of $\{7,8\}$ and not all the elements mapped into \{7,8\}? Thanks again for helping me out here.

Comment: You are right; in this case we are "asking for" all elements $n \in \omega$ which are less than $7$ or less then $8$, which amounts to those $n < 8$.

Comment: Thank you as always Maura for clarification. I have one more question: Is it correct to say that $\in_{\omega}[\{7,8\}]$ is equal to the set of all natural numbers that both $7 \& 8$ are members of - that is, the set of all natural numbers greater than 8? Answering this question will give me all of the tools to complete my homework assignment. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think that not both $7,8$, but $7$ or $8$. The image under $R$ of $A$ is : $R[A] = \{y \in B | \exists x \in A ((x,y) \in R) \}$. So, if I'm right, the answer must be :  the set of all natural numbers greater than $7$. Do you agree ?

Comment: I think perhaps you have it backward. It appears to me that given the definition of $\in_{\omega}$ that $\in^{-1}_{\omega} [\{7,8\}]$ would be the set of all natural numbers greater than 7 where as $\in_{\omega} [\{7,8\}]$ would equal $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. In either case, it does not make sense to me why they are asking for the range of two numbers since there is overlap in this case.